# trim down the error details logged by ELMAH

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, elmah

I am using Elmah for error logging and it is logging lot more info than what I need, especially all the server variables for the form in the form of Xml in database. I would like to exclude these server variables (and may be some more stuff), I am not interested in them. is it possible to configure this somewhere in web.config or do it programmatically at least?

Comment: You can never have too much logging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep them - you might not need them now, but at some point they may save your bacon.

If you're worried about space, then you're probably throwing too many exceptions...